# is it worth implementing P3P on a website/web application?

Tags: asp.net, p3p

Is it worth implementing P3P on a new asp.net website/web application?
Or any website I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of 'worth', it's whether you need to.

You'll need to if you want to host your site in an iframe on another site, and then have the cookies work, in IE.

Comment: Is this the only reason P3P may be required?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, though it's the reason we use it. It may offer other advantages, I don't know. More info here: http://www.wdvl.com/Internet/Security/P3P/

Comment: A lot of references are circa 2002 and show work-arounds for the iframe cookie thing. Since its not required, wont be implemented.
I wonder if it helps with SEO?